# How to insert data in a row using list in Python?

Tags: python, mysql

I have a list called 
`rowdata = [u'android', u'TSC', u'airtime-ctg', u'guest', u'guest', u'8354e5f4-e18d-11e6-9a46-0242ac110002', u'77c7600c502a3d15']` 
and want to enter this data in my table ctg_payload.

I have tried :

```
sqlquery = 'insert into ctg_payload (ID,logtime,hostype,hostype,group_id,group_id,deviceid) values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) ; '%(rowdata)

cursor.executemany(sqlquery)
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that using `%` but you can do that using `format` and argument unpacking:

```
sqlquery = 'insert into ctg_payload (ID,logtime,hostype,hostype,group_id,group_id,deviceid) values ({},{},{},{},{},{},{}) ; '.format(*rowdata)
```

simple example which demonstrates the capability:

```
>>> "{},{}".format(*[1,2])
'1,2'
```

and you probably mean `execute`, not `executemany` which runs execution multiple times, not what you want

Comment: tried this solution but gives me an error: executemany() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

Answer (score 1):

As Jean-François Fabre mentioned, `*rowdata` should be used in str format for your query when you execute a single query!.

And also,

You have to use [execute()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) if you want to execute one query!

> This method executes the given database operation (query or command). The parameters found in the tuple or dictionary params are bound to the variables in the operation. Specify variables using %s or %(name)s parameter style (that is, using format or pyformat style). execute() returns an iterator if multi is True.

```
data=[[u'android', u'TSC', u'airtime-ctg', u'guest', u'guest', u'8354e5f4-e18d-11e6-9a46-0242ac110002', u'77c7600c502a3d15']]

for rowdata in data:
    sqlquery = 'insert into ctg_payload (ID,logtime,hostype,hostype,group_id,group_id,deviceid) values ({},{},{},{},{},{},{}) ; '.format(*rowdata)
    cursor.execute(sqlquery)
```

And [executemany()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html) when

> This method prepares a database operation (query or command) and executes it against all parameter sequences or mappings found in the sequence seq_of_params.

```
data=[[u'android', u'TSC', u'airtime-ctg', u'guest', u'guest', u'8354e5f4-e18d-11e6-9a46-0242ac110002', u'77c7600c502a3d15']]
sqlquery = 'insert into ctg_payload (ID,logtime,hostype,hostype,group_id,group_id,deviceid) values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) '
cursor.executemany(sqlquery,data)
```

Comment: i tried using both sqlquery = 'insert into ctg_payload1 (ID,logtime,hostype,hostype,group_id,uuid,deviceid) values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) ;'.format(*rowdata)     cursor.execute(sqlquery)

Comment: sqlquery = 'insert into ctg_payload1 (ID,logtime,hostype,hostype,group_id,uuid,deviceid) values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) ;'
     cursor.executemany(sqlquery,rowdata)

Comment: what is the eror that you get? and its not ` cursor.executemany(sqlquery,rowdata)` but `cursor.executemany(sqlquery,data)`

Comment: its the same, u named it data and in my case its rowdata

Comment: Content of  rowdata is a list or list of lists? I meant list as data and list of lists and rowdata.

Comment: They aren't the same!